# Как удалить сразу несколько строк через wpdb->delete()?

Tags: php, wordpress

Данные в POST запросе приходят в виде ассоциативного массива:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["plgn_post_url"]=>
    string(110) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/17934632_1891986064378361_8110928872435875840_n
.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["plgn_post_url"]=>
    string(109) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/18382713_118552792048179_6482017612954861568_n
.jpg"
  }
}
```

Необходимо при помощи `$wpdb->delete` удалить строки из таблицы со значениями колонки, равными значениям в массиве. Колонка, по которой идет отбор в таблице, имеет такое же название как и элементы в массиве - `plgn_post_url`.
Сейчас при запросе

`$wpdb->delete($table_name, $data)`

выдает:

> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in **C:\xampp
>   \apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\wp-db.php** on line **1171**
>   "\"Error Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'\""

Comment: Приведите заголовок в соответствие с нормами русского языка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция wpdb->delete не поддерживает ничего, кроме одного значения в WHERE. Надо использовать

```
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE plgn_post_url IN($urls)" );
```

$urls должна быть строкой, в которую вы соберёте все значения plgn_post_url через запятую.

Comment: А кавычки вы туда зачем засовываете? И почему у вас пробел перед .jpg?

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ! Строку собираю вот так `$selected_pictures = "'" . implode("', '" ,json_decode( $request->get_body(), false )) . "'";`